# How can I force the transpilation of a specific package

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I'm using react-boilerplate (dev) and I get the following error when doing `npm run build:prod`

> cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config
>   internals/webpack/webpack.prod.babel.js --color -p --progress
>   --display-reasons --display-modules
>
> ..
>
> Hash: 622954faf5a47209c873
>   Version: webpack 2.6.1 Time: 18561ms
>
> ERROR in 0.ce0d924df6602f0a85c8.chunk.js from UglifyJs Unexpected
>   token: name (listeners) [0.ce0d924df6602f0a85c8.chunk.js:1265,6]
>
> ..

The section of code is:

```
1261: "use strict";
1262: Object.defineProperty(__webpack_exports__, "__esModule", { value: true });
1263: /* harmony export (immutable) */ __webpack_exports__["default"] = createBroadcast;
1264: function createBroadcast (initialState) {
1265:   let listeners = {}
1266:   let id = 0
1267:   let _state = initialState
```

It seems that this section of code is not 'transpiled' ?

I currently have:

`internals/webpack/webpack.base.babel.js`:

```
  {
    test: /\.js$/, // Transform all .js files required somewhere with Babel
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: options.babelQuery,
    },
  },
```

`package.json`:

```
  "babel": {
    "plugins": [
      "styled-components"
    ],
    "presets": [
      [
        "env",
        {
          "modules": false
        }
      ],
      "react",
      "es2015",
      "es2016",
      "stage-0"
    ],
    "env": {
      "production": {
        "only": [
          "app"
        ],
        "plugins": [
          "transform-react-remove-prop-types",
          "transform-react-constant-elements",
          "transform-react-inline-elements"
        ]
      },
      "test": {
        "plugins": [
          "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs",
          "dynamic-import-node"
        ]
      }
    }
```

I've also tried with:

```
"presets": [
  [
    "env",
    {
      "modules": false,
      "targets": {
        "uglify": 2
      }
    }
  ],
  "es2015",
  "es2016",
  "stage-0",
  "react"
],
```

Comment: Doing a development build works fine.

Comment: Is the `createBroadcast` function in a file you've written, or in `node_modules`?

Comment: It's part of a module. The one I want to transpile.

Comment: I mean specifically is it in the `node_modules` folder, not "is it part of a module". Your `exclude: /node_modules/` specifically says to ignore `node_modules` if it is in there, that's what causes it to be unconverted.

Comment: Yup, it's under node_modules (immutable) as per the error message. So far it seems the only one that cause trouble, so not sure what's so particular about this module. Hence, my idea to try and force it. I'm not sure if it's a good practice or recommended to transpile all the modules. I tried it but then I has some other packages failing.. sigh.

Comment: I'm not sure where in that error message you see it mentioning the file's location.

Answer (score 1):

The general approach if you have ES6 in node_modules would be to change

```
exclude: /node_modules/
```

to

```
exclude: /node_modules\/(?:specificModule)/
```

so that you exclude all node modules except some specific one.

Additionally, given your error

> ERROR in ./~/react-jss/lib/jss.js Module build failed: ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "transform-es3-member-expression-literals" specified in "xxxx/node_modules/react-jss/.babelrc" at 0` error

your options are limited. That means the `react-jss` module is publishing it's `.babelrc` file in its npm package, which is not recommended for exactly this reason. That config will try to run on the files in that module, but that config is using plugins that you don't have installed, and since they are probably devDependencies in `react-jss` they won't be installed normally.

The only way around this error is to disable `.babelrc` processing, or to explicitly install that plugin in your own dependencies. Neither are particularly attractive. So pass `babelrc: false` in `babelQuery` in

```
{
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  options: options.babelQuery,
}
```

and then move your Babel config out of their config files and into the Webpack config file itself.

Comment: Ok, some progress: `exclude: /node_modules\/(?:brcast)/,`: `ERROR in ./~/react-jss/lib/jss.js
Module build failed: ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "transform-es3-member-expression-literals" specified in "xxxx/node_modules/react-jss/.babelrc" at 0`

Comment: As a side note: When removing the `--optimize-minimize` switch which is not surprising

Comment: Sounds like that module is publishing a `.babelrc` to `npm` which is too bad. Generally not something Babel recommends because of this type of thing.

Comment: Seems I can not get it going. After all these modules `exclude: /node_modules\/(?:react-jss|jss-*|css-vendor|brcast|styled-components|immutable)/,`I still get the error. So finally used `babili-webpack-plugin`

Comment: As long as you don't need to support browsers that can't handle ES6 that works.

Comment: Yeah, not ideal for me now. Any other ideas? I'm running out :( Another minifier perhaps?

Comment: You specifically get the `Unknown plugin "transform-es3-member-expression-literals"` error even if you pass `babel-loader` `babelrc: false`?

Comment: Yup. In my package.json I have "presets": [
      [
        "env",
        {
          "modules": false,
          "babelrc": false
        }
      ],  Maybe it's not picked up?

Comment: No that argument is for `babel-loader` itself. It needs to be part of whatever object you're passing as `options.babelQuery`. `.babelrc` and `package.json` are both config files. `babelrc: false` disallows both of them and you'll have to move your Babel config into your Webpack config file.

Comment: Darn, seems my babelQuery is empty. I'll play around a bit with it and then come back to you. Thanks for the help so far!